# How can I apply an annotation to every method of a class?

Tags: java, annotations, metrics, spring-annotations

I have an annotation that meters the execution time placed on a method level. I would like to know if it is possible to, for  example, create a new annotation on a class level that applies my "timed" annotation on every method of this class. I'm a bit new with AOP. Maybe someone has an idea? I'm using:

- JDK 1.8

Comment: why wouldn't this be possible? the maven version you use for this is quite irrelevant.

Comment: It was just to set my environment but if you say so I remove it. Concerning the annotation, thanks for your answer first and I may have badly search on the Internet but I didn't found how to apply an annotation to every method of a class by a class level annotation. Like for example if I have a "needTimer" annotation on my class, a "timed" annotation is placed on each of its methods. I'm probably not clear, sorry I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: just make Timed be able to be put on classlevel.

Comment: @Stultuske and that's it ?

Comment: might be a bit more config work. Personally, I always use a little library I made myself, so for me: yes, that's all I would need to do. It might be that it's sufficient for you as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, I finally used Srping AOP and AspectJ to target every methods of a class (without annotation) so that it is easily deactivable.

Something like this :

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop/spring-aop-aspectj-xml-configuration-example/